# How to make prepared statement using PDO in advanced queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to ask for help with converting my mysql_* query to prepared statement using PDO technology. There are many of them which I cannot find on the internet how to solve them properly - mostly advanced ones like this one for example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pet_auction JOIN people ON (pet_auction.pet=people.guid) 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN login.account ON (pet_auction.winner=login.account.id)
            WHERE active=1 AND seller=$userid ORDER BY id DESC");
```

How to succesfully convert it to PDO STMT using these?:

```
$people = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=people", "myuser", "mypass");
$login = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login", "myuser", "mypass");
```

Thank you all I rather will not try else it would be false because i tested already ... I have no idea how to convert `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and multiple databases together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to open a pdo object for each database. Just give myuser grant access to both login and people databases. Then query like so:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=people", "myuser", "mypass");
$stmt= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM pet_auction JOIN people ON (pet_auction.pet=people.guid) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN login.account ON (pet_auction.winner=login.account.id)
        WHERE active=1 AND seller=:userid ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt-> execute(array(':userid' => $userid));
$variable = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Hmm I see .. i have a question about handling variable $userid can i just add seller=? and statement like $stmt-> execute(array($userid)); ?

Comment: And what is better or safer or does it have any difference?

Comment: They are exactly the same, just with different notations and the same cursor constraints. If you need to specify if a value is an integer or a string specifically, you would need to use the bindparam and bindvalue syntax, depending if you use :param or ? respectively.

Comment: So it is different when it is number or string (i mean the statement process) I am not familiar with bindparam and bindvalue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, "myuser", "mypass");
$select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$select -> execute();
$variable = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

where $dsn is a string containing 'mysql:dbname=racerost_reekris_db;host=localhost'

the query can contain any mySQL query including joins.